# Anchor links not clickable in Iphones/iOS devices

Tags: jquery, ios, css, iphone, wordpress

I am working on my design agency's Wordpress website and use Essential Grid plugin for a related projects slider that appears on the bottom of a project page. I have contacted support from Essential Grid and tried all the possible answers here on stack but nothing has helped. The links in question can be viewed here near the bottom of the page. [View](http://lessmore2016.accountsupport.com/work/miho/)

The issue is that when I view the related projects slider on an iPhone (iPhone 6 to be exact) the link is not clickable. However, if I hold my finger down on it for a couple seconds and let go, it loads the project. I've tried this on both Safari and Chrome and it does the same thing.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That's strange. I am not sure why not just make the next/prev buttons as actual anchor tags, instead of divs. Can you try that and see what happens? find `<div class="esg-navigationbutton ...">` and turn it into `<a href="#" class="esg-navigationbutton ...">`

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the next/prev buttons work fine, its clicking to view a project that does not work.

Comment: I see. You need to disable the `:hover` state on iPhone. You have for all `a` tags in your first line of CSS: `#navbar .logo a, a:hover, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    color: #000;
}`

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: You could try removing the `a:hover` rule and placing it in a media query, like this: `@media screen and (min-width:1025px) { a:hover { color: #000; } }` so that it will only work with desktops / laptops. Let me know if that works.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not work

Comment: Jason, I can't think of anything else but let's try this as a last resort: `#content_i8pl3r2fl .code-content {overflow:auto;}
@media (max-width: 567px) {#content_i8pl3r2fl .span12 {float:none;}}
#content_i8pl3r2fl .esg-media-cover-wrapper a {display:block;}` I'm guessing the floats are causing elements to overflow while the parent has no defined dimensions. please try this (in additional to previous comments) and tell me what happens.

Answer (score 1):

Appreciate all your help Aziz, but I figured it out. I had to apply {pointer-events: none;} to the cover divs and append the anchor to the thumbnail.